# Setting up Lightprobes

Tags: unity, lightmap, lightprobes

Moving around lightprobes requires using the movetool and all you really can do is move them along global axes and copy paste. There are no functions to scale, rotate, Snap to a surface, not even shift border select is possible. Is there a way to be more efficient setting up lightprobes?